# How do you run a regression model in R with a null hypothesis of H0 = b1 + b4 = 0?

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to fit a linear regression model that tests the null hypothesis of b1 + b4 = 0 and I understand that I need to run the model where instead of using beta1 * x1 + beta4 * x4, I need to use into beta1 * (x1-x4) but the way R runs regression models do not allow me to input a factor like this. The best I did was this but it is incorrect:

```
test2 = lm(Mortality ~ log(HCPot) + X.WC - X.NegNonWhite + income + pop.house + JulyTemp + Rain, data = pollution)
anova(model2, test2, test = 'LRT')
```

Where model2 is the same model just without the - for X.NegNonWhite. For a more clear reference, this is the original question: Using the likelihood ratio test, test the null hypothesis that the coefficients for percent white collar (X.WC) and percent non-white (X.NegNonWhite) sum to zero. Test at α = 0.05.

So we can see that there are actually 7 factors but all the negative does is remove the factor from the regression. Are there any suggetions?

Comment: If you transform your data, you can make it so the model will be of the desired form.

Comment: Do you mean that I should make a new factor before finding the difference between them first?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that x1 and x4 are two factor variables? Or are you looking for `Mortality ~ log(HCPot) + I(X.WC - X.NegNonWhite) + income + pop.house + JulyTemp + Rain`?

Comment: Yes the latter is what I want.